# Is quadro gv100 suitable for high performance computing?

Tags: gpu

I want to buy a GPU for high performance computing. As far as I know, the computation power Tflops of quadro GV100 and tesla V100 is very very similar, and Quadro GV100 is even higher.

The specification of quadro GV100: 
[image]

The specification of tesla v100:
[image]

But there are some obvious difference, it seems that Quadro GV100 has more functions, such as VR, graphics. But in the "computer APIs", I notice Quadro GV100 lacks openacc support.

I don't understand, since the core of Quadro GV100 and tesla v100 is the same(that is GV100), why openacc is not supported by Quadro GV100? Are there important structure differences between Quadro GV100 and tesla V100 so that Quadro GV100 can not support openacc? Can openacc be supported by future driver update for Quadro GV100? Is openacc important for GPU computation, especially I need to use it for First principle calculation like vasp software? Is the performance of Quadro GV100 really the same as Tesla V100 for high performance computation considering Quadro GV100 add many additional functionalities?

Comment: OpenACC requires hardware support due to the fact, the code that you would compile, would be (Nvidia) assembly.  So it entirely depends on the specifics of the computing tasks.

Comment: @Ramhound Hi, Thank you for comment. But hardware core of these two GPUs are the same(GV100), why Quadro GV100 doesn't support openacc?

Comment: One of the many reasons would be they would use different drivers.  Their hardware would also be different.  Just because they use GV100 does not mean they have the same functionality.  Nvidia can disable features within the firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I've purchased GV100 instead of V100 due to a huge pricing difference (I was told if you buy them in bulk, V100 is much more economically viable, but vice versa in low quantities).

I use it for Materials Science, and I do confirm it works well with VASP, LAMMPS and my home brew codes, with no significant difference with V100 equipped nodes in HPC cluster.

I think the capability of doubling the GPU addressable memory by interconnecting the cards is what matters most, and is present in GV100.

Please note that, CPU memory and PCI capabilities matter a lot in this equation. The idea is to be able to transfer data from system memory to GPU memory via PCI efficiently, and especially consumer level CPUs are not very good with that.